# Run multiple python scripts, that use user inputs and while loops, simultaneously

Tags: python

Basically I need to run three files simultaneously and independently. These files are started with a user input followed by an infinite While Loop.

I have found some questions similar to mine but the solutions do not quite fit my needs. I am still a beginner.

I have already tried:

```
python device1.py &
python device2.py &
python device3.py
```

I also tried doing this all in one file but the file is rather large and complicated, and have not succeeded thus far.

```py
#some code that creates a csv

#input
device = input("input which device you want to connect to")

def function():
    #write to csv file from data

while True:
    #get live data from device

    #csv function
    function()
```

I expect to enter 3 inputs for my 3 scripts, they run their loops, I end the code and have 3 csv files.

Comment: Have you looked at the multiprocessing and threading libraries in python?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will check it out.

Comment: I tried threading, but for some reason I am getting a string index error  now when I look at the last element of a list via "mylist[-1]". I did not have this problem when running one instance of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the input in your command?

```
echo inputForDevice1 | python device1.py &
echo inputForDevice2 | python device2.py &
echo inputForDevice3 | python device3.py &
```

Also remember to detach from the last python call (`python device3.py &`), otherwise you'll be stuck in the infinite loop.

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain the "echo inputforDeviceX" when I looked up "echo" it said Python does not have a function and that I am likely confusing it for a keyword in PHP? What is the syntax? How is it plugging the input into each of my scripts?